# What is the sequence of the Boya Chinese textbooks?

Tags: books

I have some *Boya Chinese* textbooks and want to buy more to have a complete set to work through. Searching for the books, I find very strange naming conventions. Here are some examples:

- Elementary 1
- Elementary Start
- Intermediate I
- Quasai-Intermediate 1
- Intermediate Spurt I
- Advanced Hover III
- Pre-Intermediate Speed-Up
- Reading and Writing

If I want to buy and work through a complete set, including any corresponding workbooks, what is the order?

Answer (score 2):

I haven’t heard of this series before, but looking at information from the publisher ([Peking University Press](http://www.pup.cn)) and various booksellers I can see the following:

**博雅汉语 = Boya Chinese** (1st edition, published around 2004–2009)

- 初级起步篇I = Elementary starter I
- 初级起步篇II = Elementary starter II
- 准中级加速篇I = Pre-intermediate speed up I
- 准中级加速篇II = Pre-intermediate speed up II
- 中级冲刺篇I = Intermediate spurt I
- 中级冲刺篇II = Intermediate spurt II
- 高级飞翔篇I = Advanced hover I
- 高级飞翔篇II = Advanced hover II
- 高级飞翔篇III = Advanced hover III

**博雅汉语 = Boya Chinese** (2nd edition, published around 2012–2016)

- 初级起步篇I = Elementary I
- 初级起步篇II = Elementary II
- 准中级加速篇I = Quasi-intermediate I
- 准中级加速篇II = Quasi-intermediate II
- 中级冲刺篇I = Intermediate I
- 中级冲刺篇II = Intermediate II
- 高级飞翔篇I = Advanced I
- 高级飞翔篇II = Advanced II

In addition to these main textbooks there are various extras, like the *Guide books* aimed mainly at teachers and *Reading and writing* giving extra resources.